# Google Chart Tools with PHP & MySQl

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a chart using the Google Visualization API, with PHP & MySQL in the background.

What I'm doing is:

- getting the data from db using PHP / SQL

  ```
  $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Chart");
  ```
- creating JSON with PHP

  ```
  $rows = array();

  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }

  $jdata = json_encode($rows);
  ```
- and then feeding Google Visualization API with JSON

  ```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jdata ?>);
  ```

Just to make sure the JSON is actually in the correct format I did:

```
$jdata = json_encode($rows);
print $jdata;
```

which returned:

```
[{"id":"1","quarters":"1","salary":"1250"},{"id":"2","quarters":"2","salary":"2500"},{"id":"3","quarters":"3","salary":"4526"},{"id":"4","quarters":"4","salary":"4569"}]
```

So,

- db connection is OK.
- creating JSON from PHP array is OK.
- JSON format is OK.

Firebug is returning an error saying:

> Table has no columns.
>   [Break On This Error] b,Sl),[b]}function Zq(a,b){var c=a[xc]..."].")):d(l("Table has no columns."))}

The question is how can I create columns from JSON data?

**UPDATE:**

Code used to create the graph below:

```
// SQL Query
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Chart");
//$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
   if(!isset($google_JSON)){    
     $google_JSON = "{cols: [";    
     $column = array_keys($r);
     foreach($column as $key=>$value){
         $google_JSON_cols[]="{id: '".$key."', label: '".$value."'}";
     }    
     $google_JSON .= implode(",",$google_JSON_cols)."],rows: [";       
   }
   $google_JSON_rows[] = "{c:[{v: '".$r['id']."'}, {v: '".$r['quarters']."'}, {v: '".$r['salary']."'}]}";
}    

// you may need to change the above into a function that loops through rows, with $r['id'] etc, referring to the fields you want to inject..

$data = $google_JSON.implode(",",$google_JSON_rows)."]}";
```

**Output HTML CODE:**

```
        <!-- load Google AJAX API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        //load the Google Visualization API and the chart  
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['columnchart']});  

        //set callback  
        google.setOnLoadCallback (createChart);  

        //callback function  
        function createChart() {  

            //create data table object  
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({cols: [{id: '0', label: 'id'},{id: '1', label: 'quarters'},{id: '2', label: 'salary'}],rows: [{c:[{v: '1'}, {v: '1'}, {v: '1250'}]},{c:[{v: '2'}, {v: '2'}, {v: '2500'}]},{c:[{v: '3'}, {v: '3'}, {v: '4526'}]},{c:[{v: '4'}, {v: '4'}, {v: '4569'}]}]});  

            //instantiate our chart objects  
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart (document.getElementById('chart'));  

            //define options for visualization  
            var options = {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true, title: 'Company Earnings'};  

            //draw our chart  
            chart.draw(data, options);  

        }  
    </script>

    <div id="chart"></div>
```

[image: When using the code above the script is creating the graph, but something is wrong there]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html), have you tried establishing the column references and data seperately?

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
data.addRows([
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep', {v:7, f:'7.000'}]
]);
```

To format into the correct JSON for the object, you can set it up as follows:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
   if(!isset($google_JSON)){    
     $google_JSON = "{cols: [";    
     $column = array_keys($r);
     foreach($column as $key=>$value){
         $google_JSON_cols[]="{id: '".$key."', label: '".$value."'}";
     }    
     $google_JSON .= implode(",",$google_JSON_cols)."],rows: [";       
   }
   $google_JSON_rows[] = "{c:[{v: '".$r['id']."'}, {v: ".$r['quarters']."}, {v: ".$r['salary']."}]}";
}    
// you may need to change the above into a function that loops through rows, with $r['id'] etc, referring to the fields you want to inject..
echo $google_JSON.implode(",",$google_JSON_rows)."]}";
```

Comment: Yep, I did. And it does work. The quastion how to create column from JSON?

Comment: JSON needs to be in the format: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#dataparam

Comment: Any idea how can I convert that JSON into the correct format in JS / PHP ?

Comment: I've updated the answer, you may need to tweak but it'll give you an approximate idea

Comment: Does this mean the columns need to hard-coded? Can't they be extracted from JSON? I must admit it does look complicated. Thanks!

Comment: No, not at all- you can spit them out during the routine- I've edited the above

Comment: Ok, the script is creating the graph, but something is wrong there. Have a look http://awesomescreenshot.com/05flx352a.

Comment: orry- I was referencing to the output code, e.d. the source you get when you right click the output page and click 'view source'

Comment: OK, I've updated the code, though note that the graph is showing 'quarters' and 'salary' together, one is on a scale of tens, the other on thousands...so the graph isnt a great output

Comment: If you only have four rows (one for each quarter), you may wish to change your select SQL to only show quarters and salary.

Comment: Ok. It is working! Thank you very much for your time and effort! I will do some code analysing now! As you code is very mysterious to me ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Complete Working Example: PHP/MYSQL/Google Chart/JSON
```

[PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994282/php-mysql-google-chart-json-complete-example)

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the link goes down, the only useful information here is that there might be something called "PHP MYSQL Google Chart JSON Complete Example" that might be worth searching for, which does not answer the problem.