# PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example

Tags: php, mysql, json, charts, google-visualization

I have searched a lot to find a good example for generating a Google Chart using MySQL table data as the data source. I searched for a couple of days and realised that there are few examples available for generating a Google Chart (pie, bar, column, table) using a combination of PHP and MySQL. I finally managed to get one example working.

I have previously received a lot of help from StackOverflow, so this time I will return some.

I have two examples; one uses Ajax and the other does not. Today, I will only show the non-Ajax example.

**Usage:**

```
    Requirements: PHP, Apache and MySQL

    Installation:

      --- Create a database by using phpMyAdmin and name it "chart"
      --- Create a table by using phpMyAdmin and name it "googlechart" and make 
          sure table has only two columns as I have used two columns. However, 
          you can use more than 2 columns if you like but you have to change the 
          code a little bit for that
      --- Specify column names as follows: "weekly_task" and "percentage"
      --- Insert some data into the table
      --- For the percentage column only use a number

          ---------------------------------
          example data: Table (googlechart)
          ---------------------------------

          weekly_task     percentage
          -----------     ----------
          Sleep           30
          Watching Movie  10
          job             40
          Exercise        20
```

**PHP-MySQL-JSON-Google Chart  Example:**

```
    <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","Username","Password") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("Database Name", $con); 
// The Chart table contains two fields: weekly_task and percentage
// This example will display a pie chart. If you need other charts such as a Bar chart, you will need to modify the code a little to make it work with bar chart and other charts
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chart");

/*
---------------------------
example data: Table (Chart)
--------------------------
weekly_task     percentage
Sleep           30
Watching Movie  40
work            44
*/

//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Weekly_task']); 

    // Values of each slice
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'My Weekly Plan',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP-PDO-JSON-MySQL-Google Chart Example:**

```
<?php
    /*
    Script  : PHP-PDO-JSON-mysql-googlechart
    Author  : Enam Hossain
    version : 1.0

    */

    /*
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Usage:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------

    Requirements: PHP, Apache and MySQL

    Installation:

      --- Create a database by using phpMyAdmin and name it "chart"
      --- Create a table by using phpMyAdmin and name it "googlechart" and make sure table has only two columns as I have used two columns. However, you can use more than 2 columns if you like but you have to change the code a little bit for that
      --- Specify column names as follows: "weekly_task" and "percentage"
      --- Insert some data into the table
      --- For the percentage column only use a number

          ---------------------------------
          example data: Table (googlechart)
          ---------------------------------

          weekly_task     percentage
          -----------     ----------

          Sleep           30
          Watching Movie  10
          job             40
          Exercise        20     


    */

    /* Your Database Name */
    $dbname = 'chart';

    /* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '123456';

    try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      /* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
      $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM googlechart');

      /*
          ---------------------------
          example data: Table (googlechart)
          --------------------------
          weekly_task     percentage
          Sleep           30
          Watching Movie  10
          job             40
          Exercise        20       
      */



      $rows = array();
      $table = array();
      $table['cols'] = array(

        // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
        /* 
            note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format 
            as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage 
            and string will be used for Slice title
        */

        array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

    );
        /* Extract the information from $result */
        foreach($result as $r) {

          $temp = array();

          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

          $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['weekly_task']); 

          // Values of each slice

          $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']); 
          $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    //echo $jsonTable;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>


    <html>
      <head>
        <!--Load the Ajax API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
          var options = {
               title: 'My Weekly Plan',
              is3D: 'true',
              width: 800,
              height: 600
            };
          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          // Do not forget to check your div ID
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**PHP-MySQLi-JSON-Google Chart Example**

```
<?php
/*
Script  : PHP-JSON-MySQLi-GoogleChart
Author  : Enam Hossain
version : 1.0

*/

/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Requirements: PHP, Apache and MySQL

Installation:

  --- Create a database by using phpMyAdmin and name it "chart"
  --- Create a table by using phpMyAdmin and name it "googlechart" and make sure table has only two columns as I have used two columns. However, you can use more than 2 columns if you like but you have to change the code a little bit for that
  --- Specify column names as follows: "weekly_task" and "percentage"
  --- Insert some data into the table
  --- For the percentage column only use a number

      ---------------------------------
      example data: Table (googlechart)
      ---------------------------------

      weekly_task     percentage
      -----------     ----------

      Sleep           30
      Watching Movie  10
      job             40
      Exercise        20     


*/

/* Your Database Name */

$DB_NAME = 'chart';

/* Database Host */
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';

/* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '123456';





  /* Establish the database connection */
  $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

   /* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
  $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM googlechart');

  /*
      ---------------------------
      example data: Table (googlechart)
      --------------------------
      Weekly_Task     percentage
      Sleep           30
      Watching Movie  10
      job             40
      Exercise        20       
  */



  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
    /* 
        note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format 
        as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage 
        and string will be used for Slice title
    */

    array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['weekly_task']); 

      // Values of the each slice

      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;


?>


<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'My Weekly Plan',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 9):

Some might encounter this error either locally or on the server:

```
syntax error var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
```

This means that their environment does not support short tags the solution is to use this instead:

```
<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>
```

And everything should work fine!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this more easy way. And 100% works that you want

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";  //your database password
    $dbname = "demo";  //your database name

    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    }
    else
    {
        //echo ("Connect Successfully");
    }
    $query = "SELECT Date_time, Tempout FROM alarm_value"; // select column
    $aresult = $con->query($query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Massive Electronics</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Date_time','Tempout'],
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)){
                        echo "['".$row["Date_time"]."', ".$row["Tempout"]."],";
                    }
                ?>
               ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Date_time Vs Room Out Temp',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('areachart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="areachart" style="width: 900px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

loder.js link here [loder.js](https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js)

Answer (score 0):

use this, it realy works:

data.addColumn no of your key, you can add more columns or remove

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","USername","Password") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("Database Name", $con); 
// The Chart table contain two fields: Weekly_task and percentage
//this example will display a pie chart.if u need other charts such as Bar chart, u will need to change little bit to make work with bar chart and others charts
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chart");

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$arr2=array_keys($r);
$arr1=array_values($r);

}

for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
{
    $chart_array[$i]=array((string)$arr2[$i],intval($arr1[$i]));
}
echo "<pre>";
$data=json_encode($chart_array);
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "YEAR");
        data.addColumn("number", "NO of record");

        data.addRows(<?php $data ?>);

        ]); 
      var options = {
           title: 'My Weekly Plan',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      //do not forget to check ur div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```