# Multi line Google Line Chart, using data from mySQL db

Tags: php, json, mysqli, charts, google-visualization

I'm going through a bit of a learning process, in order to create a small database backed reporting system for my company.

The intent is to draw a multi line chart using Google Charts, based on a mysql database.

I've managed to get the data to echo from the mysql database, but it's not generating the chart. All I get is the echo, and a blank space where the chart should be. The echo is shown for debugging purposes.

Here is the code :

```
<?php include 'confile.php';

$qry = "SELECT time,p1,p2,p3,p4 from $db WHERE date = '2016-03-02' ORDER BY time ASC";
$result = $conn->query($qry);

if($result === FALSE) {
    echo mysql_errno($result) .": ". mysql_error($result) ."/n";
    die(mysql_error());
}

$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
                        array('label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
                        array('label' => 'Probe 1', 'type' => 'number'),
                        array('label' => 'Probe 2', 'type' => 'number'),
                        array('label' => 'Probe 3', 'type' => 'number'),
                        array('label' => 'Probe 4', 'type' => 'number')
                        );

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array($r['time']);

    $temp[] = array($r['p1']);
    $temp[] = array($r['p2']);              
    $temp[] = array($r['p3']);
    $temp[] = array($r['p4']);

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);  
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?$jsonTable?>);
        var options = {
            title: 'Recorded Temperatures',
            legend: {position: 'bottom' },
            width: 800,
            height: 600
        }; 

        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);  
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the 'echo' output

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Time","type":"datetime"},{"label":"Probe 1","type":"number"},{"label":"Probe 2","type":"number"},{"label":"Probe 3","type":"number"},{"label":"Probe 4","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[["03:02:07"],["270.26"],["298.40"],["111.54"],["228.06"]]},{"c":[["03:28:42"],["273.23"],["190.43"],["245.69"],["283.21"]]},{"c":[["07:26:04"],["144.33"],["217.26"],["206.53"],["167.68"]]},{"c":[["12:13:20"],["153.15"],["277.23"],["167.20"],["240.88"]]}]}
```

This is test data, using a test query on the db. Once I understand the formatting to render the chart, it will be setup to allow the user to select which date to view, etc.

This was the closest existing question I can find, but doesn't seem to answer the question.

[Not able to generate a Google Chart using MySQL table data as the data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752165/not-able-to-generate-a-google-chart-using-mysql-table-data-as-the-data-source)

---

Following the answer of @MickMackusa, I managed to hack this together to get it to work, by ensuring the mysql/php array was output in a manner acceptable to Google Charts.

Thanks to @MickMacUSA for his assistance.

The final, working code, is below.

```
<?php include 'confile.php';

$qry = "SELECT time,p1,p2,p3,p4 from $db WHERE date = '2016-04-16' ORDER BY time ASC";
$result = $conn->query($qry);

if($result === FALSE) {
    echo mysqli_errno($result) .": ". mysqli_error($result) ."/n";
    die(mysqli_error());
}
    $i = 0; //iteration counter - start at 0

    $totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // we need this to know when to change the output
    $targetRows = $totalRows - 1; //row indies start from 0, not 1.

    foreach ($result as $row){ 

        $comTime = str_replace(":",",",$row['time']); // for each row, remove the : and put , in its place
        if ($targetRows == $i) { // if the index is the same value as the target (ie, it's the last row)...

            $temp = "[[".$comTime."],".($row['p1']).",".($row['p2']).",".($row['p3']).",".($row['p4'])."]". PHP_EOL;
            } else {
            $temp = "[[".$comTime."],".($row['p1']).",".($row['p2']).",".($row['p3']).",".($row['p4'])."],". PHP_EOL;
            }
        $i = $i + 1; 
        $rows[] = $temp; 
    }

 $table = $rows;
 $data = implode($table); //format the table as a single string, with line returns

//echo $i;
//echo $data;

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart(){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('timeofday','Time'); 
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 1');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 2');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 3');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 4');

            data.addRows([              
                <?php echo $data; ?> //dump the result into here, as it's correctly formatted   
            ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Recorded Temperatures',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            hAxis: { format: 'hh:mm:ss' }
        }; 

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);    
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try not to fix up your question too much, or you'll steal my thunder and the points in my answer won't make sense.  I might like to ask you to roll the edit back, because you don't need to correct your original message to tell the _story_.

Comment: Rolled back, as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number values must be formatted differently and you want `timeofday` not `datetime`.

According to: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Format your data to look like this:

```
{cols:
    [
        {"label":"Time","type":"timeofday"},
        {"label":"Probe 1","type":"number"},
        {"label":"Probe 2","type":"number"},
        {"label":"Probe 3","type":"number"},
        {"label":"Probe 4","type":"number"}
    ],
rows:
    [
        {c:[{v:[03,02,07],f:'03:02:07'},{v:270.26},{v:298.40},{v:111.54},{v:228.06}]},
        {c:[{v:[03,28,42],f:'03:28:42'},{v:273.23},{v:190.43},{v:245.69},{v:283.21}]},
        {c:[{v:[07,26,04],f:'07:26:04'},{v:144.33},{v:217.26},{v:206.53},{v:167.68}]},
        {c:[{v:[12,13,20],f:'12:13:20'},{v:153.15},{v:277.23},{v:167.20},{v:240.88}]}
    ]
}
```

And you must echo it in the javascript:

change:

```
<?$jsonTable?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>
```

And put your javascript code block just before your `</body>` tag.

This is the full working code using the above data format that I tested on my server:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart(){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
            {cols:[
                {"label":"Time","type":"timeofday"},
                {"label":"Probe 1","type":"number"},
                {"label":"Probe 2","type":"number"},
                {"label":"Probe 3","type":"number"},
                {"label":"Probe 4","type":"number"}
            ],
            rows:[
                {c:[{v:[03,02,07],f:'03:02:07'},{v:270.26},{v:298.40},{v:111.54},{v:228.06}]},
                {c:[{v:[03,28,42],f:'03:28:42'},{v:273.23},{v:190.43},{v:245.69},{v:283.21}]},
                {c:[{v:[07,26,04],f:'07:26:04'},{v:144.33},{v:217.26},{v:206.53},{v:167.68}]},
                {c:[{v:[12,13,20],f:'12:13:20'},{v:153.15},{v:277.23},{v:167.20},{v:240.88}]}
            ]
        });

        var options = {
            title: 'Recorded Temperatures',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            hAxis: { format: 'hh:mm:ss' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);   
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### This is an alternative format that will be simpler/clearer/easier to build/comprehend using your mysqli results:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart(){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('timeofday','Time');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 1');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 2');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 3');
            data.addColumn('number','Probe 4');
        data.addRows([
            [[03,02,07],270.26,298.40,111.54,228.06],
            [[03,28,42],273.23,190.43,245.69,283.21],
            [[07,26,04],144.33,217.26,206.53,167.68],
            [[12,13,20],153.15,277.23,167.20,240.88]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Recorded Temperatures',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            hAxis: { format: 'hh:mm:ss' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);   
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

See the SO Demo provided by [WhiteHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090771/whitehat):

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({cols: [
      {"label":"Time","type":"timeofday"},
      {"label":"Probe 1","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Probe 2","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Probe 3","type":"number"},
      {"label":"Probe 4","type":"number"}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c:[{v:[03,02,07],f:'03:02:07'},{v:270.26},{v:298.40},{v:111.54},{v:228.06}]},
      {c:[{v:[03,28,42],f:'03:28:42'},{v:273.23},{v:190.43},{v:245.69},{v:283.21}]},
      {c:[{v:[07,26,04],f:'07:26:04'},{v:144.33},{v:217.26},{v:206.53},{v:167.68}]},
      {c:[{v:[12,13,20],f:'12:13:20'},{v:153.15},{v:277.23},{v:167.20},{v:240.88}]}
    ]
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_0'));
  table.draw(data);

  var options = {
      title: 'Recorded Temperatures',
      legend: {position: 'bottom' },
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      hAxis: {
        format: 'hh:mm:ss'
      }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_0"></div>
<div id="chart_1"></div>
```

Comment: @StevenDavison after implementing my suggested echo in the javascript, is your json being displayed in the page's source code?  Please confirm that.

Comment: The json data is always displayed by echo $jsonTable; on line 38. It is not repeated.

Comment: It's not being echoed from the javascript portion of the code, but I wouldn't expect it to be, as it's being passed as the data for the Google chart.

Comment: Aha, I see. Yes, it's being echoed.

Comment: @StevenDavison I just fixed some typos in my answer.  Please do a temporary hardcode of my version of your data and plug it into your code and tell me if it runs.

Comment: looks good to me -- also noticed in the question -- a `Table` chart is being used but the `'table'` package hasn't been loaded --> `var chart = new google.visualization.Table`

Comment: @Whitehat Well, Spotted... edited. 
Mickmackusa - I've put the code as suggested, and the chart still doesn't render.

Comment: @WhiteHat  That's a beautiful touch, thanks for that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141368/discussion-between-steven-davison-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: @StevenDavison  I've found an easier/better format for your data coming from mysqli.  Please see my updated answer and scroll to the second html file that I've provided.  Please run my file in your environment and see if it works for you.  My new version hardcodes the `cols` (because it probably won't change much for your project), and only asks for dynamic `rows` data.  The new rows data format doesn't need any of those extra keys or curly brackets.  If it works you'll only need to adjust your php array and echo it in the javascript.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: You are correct with your assumption of the cols, the headers won't be changing dyamically. Your solution works, for the hard-coded test data.

Comment: So developing this further, and I've managed to get the dynamic data into the table, formatted correctly, bar one thing. The time is being presented to the chart in hh:mm:ss format, whereas the data in the hardcoded version is hh,mm,ss. 

in the db, the time is stored as a mysql 'time' which is shown as hh:mm:ss.