# Laravel5.0: passing value from a controller method to a .php file in public folder

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to pass a value from my controller to a .php file which is inside public folder. 
This is my controller part

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class DashboardController extends Controller {

public function barChart(){

    $barChart= DB::table('clients')
        ->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')
        ->get();
    //want to pass this $barChart variable
}
```

Location of .php file is

```
/dist/chart/clients.php
```

I want to have this $barChart variable in clients.php file and perform further operation.

update 1:
this is the view part

```
    <div class="panel-body" id="barChart">

    </div>



    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        //url: "{{URL::asset('/dist/chart/clients.txt')}}", //this works, I saved the json_encode($bar) at client.txt file
        data: [{{$bar}}], //this does not work
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result){
            google.charts.load('current',{
            'packages':['corechart']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
            drawChart(result);
            });
        }
        });

        function drawChart(result) {server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string' , 'ClientName');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
            var dataArray=[];
            $.each(result, function(i, obj){
            dataArray.push([obj.ClientName, parseInt(obj.Price)]);
        });
        data.addRows(dataArray);

            var barChart_options = {
            title: 'hoise??',
            is3D: 'true',
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        };
        var barChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
                    barChart.draw(data, barChart_options);
        }
});


</script>
```

update 2

controller update

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class DashboardController extends Controller {


public function index()
{

    try{
        $val=DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()) {

            $barChart= DB::table('clients')
                ->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')
                ->get();
            $bar = json_encode($barChart);

            return view('home')
                ->with('bar', $bar);

        }else{
            $er="/connection status: database error";
            return view('errors/503')->with('error',$er);
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        $er="/connection status: database error";
        return view('errors/503')->with('error',$er);
    }

}

public function barChart(){

    $barChart= DB::table('clients')
        ->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')
        ->get();
    echo json_encode($barChart);
}
public function create()
{
    //
}
public function store()
{
    //
}
public function show($id)
{
    //
}
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}
public function update($id)
{
    //
}
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

Comment: why are you not sending it to a view?

Comment: Instead create a blade file and simply access the values over there.

Comment: inside my view I want to use that $barChart variable json_encoded. $.ajax({
     url: "{{URL::asset('/dist/chart/clients.php')}}",
      dataType:"JSON",
      success: function(result){
      google.charts.load('current',{
      'packages':['corechart']
      });

Comment: plz post your controller update too.

Comment: @MubasharAbbas please check the update

Comment: and where is your view file home.blade.php located in your directory structure?

Comment: resource\views\home.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

Add your `clients.php` to `resources/views` directory and name it `clients.blade.php`, it will work the same but give you a nice templating engine.

In your `controller/barChart` method do this.

```
$barChart= DB::table('clients')
    ->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')
    ->get();
return view('clients', compact('barChart'));
```

In the view file `resources/views/clients.blade.php` you can now access the `$barChart` variable.

You can use it in your view like this:

```
{{ json_encode($barChart) }}
```

or if you are not using blade, then

```
<?= json_encode($barChart) ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but, I can't use $barChart as an url inside $.ajax({url: }) . The very reason I asked this question so that I can use the output of json_encode($barChart) ,  inside $.ajax({url: ..here... }) in my view. Integrating google chart is made me do this. If you know a better way to integrate google chart with laravel with the value from mysql database please tell me.

Comment: you need to send it as data property of ajax right?

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it didn't work for me. I updated my question. please look at it. It might help you to understand my problem clearly.

Comment: in my answer I mentioned putting your clients.php file in resources/views. Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put your clients.php to res`enter code here`ources/views directory and name it clients.blade.php

Change your controller like

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class DashboardController extends Controller {
public function barChart(){
$barChart=DB::table('clients')
->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')-  >get();
return view('clients')->with('barChart' => $barChart);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well finally I came up with the solution. I can't pass variable to public folder and giving the ulr in ajax was also a problem in that case creating the data table is obvous then pass it.
the controller part will be

```
public function index()
{
    try{
        $val=DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
        if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()) {

            $barChart= DB::table('clients')
                ->select('clients.ClientName','clients.Price')
                ->get();

            $rows = array();
            //flag is not needed
            $flag = true;
            $table = array();
            $table['cols'] = array(
                array('label' => 'Weekly Task', 'type' => 'string'),
                array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

            );

            $rows = array();
            foreach($barChart as $r) {
                $temp = array();
                $temp[] = array('v' => (String)$r->ClientName);
                $temp[] = array('v' =>(int)$r->Price);
                $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
            }

            $table['rows'] = $rows;
            $bar = json_encode($table);





            return view('home')
                ->with('bar', $bar);

        }else{
        }
    }catch (\Exception $e){
    }

}
```

The view part will be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

                        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                        function drawChart() {

                            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$bar?>);
                            var options = {
                                title: 'My Chart',
                                is3D: 'true',
                                width: 400,
                                height: 300
                            };
                            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                            // Do not forget to check your div ID
                            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
                            chart.draw(data, options);
                        }
                    </script>
```

courtesy 
[php mysql google chart json complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994282/php-mysql-google-chart-json-complete-example)