# Transform data to make a Google Chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, google-visualization

I have this data in my summary table:

```
REGIS_ID    VAC_NAME    LOC_DETAIL
1   Flu University
2   Flu University
3   Flu University
4   Flu Office
5   Flu School
6   Flu Office
7   Flu School
8   Flu School
9   Flu School
10  Flu School
11  Flu University
12  Flu University
13  Hepatitis-B School
14  Hepatitis-B School
15  Hepatitis-B School
16  Hepatitis-B Office
17  Hepatitis-B Office
18  Bird_Flu    University
19  Bird_Flu    University
20  Bird_Flu    School
21  Bird_Flu    School
22  Bird_Flu    School
23  Bird_Flu    Office
24  Bird_Flu    Office
25  Bird_Flu    University
```

so I want to query and transform data to PHP like this:

```
$dataTest = "['', 'Bird_Flu', 'Flu', 'Hepatitis-B'],
['School', 3, 5, 2],
['University', 3, 5, 3],
['Office', 2, 2, 2]";
```

in order to make a Google Chart:

[image: Google Chart]

What should I do? Thank you so much.

Comment: [PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12994282/5090771)

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing in the past, I just used code to build up the string in the required format

```
//sudo code
$dataTest = ""
foreach(datarow)
{
    $dataTest += "['School', 3, 5, 2],"
}
```