# Ajax on dropdown change. Chart data change

Tags: php, ajax, google-visualization

i'm trying to use AJAX to communicate with the servers to change my chart data whenever the user selects an option in my dropdown box. They would be selecting the year and I want the chart data to change based on the year they select. Heading into the database, using sql to get the required data for my chart, then i would draw it out using Google-visualisation scattered chart. I've seen examples of echoing out the results in a table using the  and  tags with ajax but I can't seem to redraw my chart in a similar way.

Index.php file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">


google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMouseoverVisualization);
    var barsVisualization;

    function drawMouseoverVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Quarter');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');

      data.addRows([[1,result1],[2,result2],[3,result3],[4,result4]]);

      var options={
          hAxis: {title: 'Quarter'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Frequency'},
          trendlines: {0: {type: 'exponential',
                           color: 'red'
            }}
      };

      barsVisualization = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
      barsVisualization.draw(data, options);

      // Add our over/out handlers.
    }
    </script>
    <script>
 function getchart(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getData.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form>
        <select name="year" id="year" onchange="getchart(this.value)">
            <?php
            echo "<option>Select year</option>";
            for ($i=2016;$i<date("Y")+10;$i++){
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

getData.php file:

```
$q=$_GET['q'];
$i=$q;
$i0=$i.'-01-01';

$i1=$i.'-03-31';
$i2=$i.'-06-31';
$i3=$i.'-09-31';
$i4=$i.'-12-31';


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hi')or die ("Error :". mysqli_connect_error());

$qry1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE Category LIKE '%IT%'AND Date<='$i1'";

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$qry1);

$qry2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE Category LIKE '%IT%' AND Date<='$i2' AND Date>'$i1'";

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$qry2);

$qry3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE Category LIKE '%IT%' AND Date<='$i3' AND Date>'$i2'";

$result3 = mysqli_query($con,$qry3);

$qry4 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE Category LIKE '%IT%' AND Date<='$i4' AND Date>'$i3'";

$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$qry4);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        $count1 = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    }
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $count2 = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    }
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
        $count3 = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    }
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)){
        $count4 = $row['COUNT(*)'];
    }
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var result1 = <?php echo $count1 ?>;
 var result2 = <?php echo $count2 ?>;
 var result3 = <?php echo $count3 ?>;
 var result4 = <?php echo $count4 ?>;
 </script>
```

Comment: im sorry but i dont really know where i went wrong~ when i run the program, nothing shows up! i tried so many times with this but none of it works.

Comment: seen this --> [PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12994282/5090771)?

Comment: yup but it doesn't show ajax examples. I can successfully draw the chart from the data in my database but now the issue is changing the data of the chart from my database without refreshing the whole page.