# create Chart using Chartjs and PHP

Tags: php, chart.js

I need to create a chart using chartJS which gets the data from mysql, below is a sample output from mysql table:

```
+----+------------+----------+-----------------+----------
| ID | DATE       | Time     | Create | Delete | Product |
+----+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | 03/12/2017 | 09:00:00 |     28 |   1264 |      59 |
```

ive managed to put the data in JSON format, using the toturial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994282/php-mysql-google-chart-json-complete-example), below is the PHP file:

**get.php**

```
<?php

$DB_NAME = 'testDB';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$db_port = '3306';
$DB_USER = 'test';
$DB_PASS = 'mysql';
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  $result = $mysqli->query('Select * from (SELECT * FROM Stats ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 48)t ORDER BY id ASC');
  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'string'),
   array('label' => 'ProductCreate', 'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'ProductDelete', 'type' => 'number'),
   array('label' => 'ProductRenew', 'type' => 'number')

);
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Time']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Create']);
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Delete']);
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Renew']);

      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$SubsStats = json_encode($table);
echo $SubsStats;


?>
```

My question now is how can I include the PHP output into my HTML file and draw the chart using ChartJS?

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: Use above "SubsStats" json data and pass to javacript function for creating chart with help of chartJS supported function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsanz/uLUAT/)

```js
var data = {
 labels : ["January","February","March",
              "April","May","June",
              "July","Agost","September",
              "October","November","December"],
 datasets : [
  {
   fillColor : "rgba(252,233,79,0.5)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(82,75,25,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(166,152,51,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   data : <?php echo $res; ?>
  }
 ]
}


var options={     
 //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data   
 scaleOverlay : false,
 
 //Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
 scaleOverride : true,
 
 //** Required if scaleOverride is true **
 //Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
 scaleSteps : 14,
 //Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
 scaleStepWidth : 5,
 //Number - The scale starting value
 scaleStartValue : 55,
 //String - Colour of the scale line 
 scaleLineColor : "rgba(20,20,20,.7)",
 
 //Number - Pixel width of the scale line 
 scaleLineWidth : 1,

 //Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale 
 scaleShowLabels : true,
 
 //Interpolated JS string - can access value
 scaleLabel : "<%=value%>",
 
 //String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
 scaleFontFamily : "'Arial'",
 
 //Number - Scale label font size in pixels 
 scaleFontSize : 12,
 
 //String - Scale label font weight style 
 scaleFontStyle : "normal",
 
 //String - Scale label font colour 
 scaleFontColor : "#666", 
 
 ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
 scaleShowGridLines : true,
 
 //String - Colour of the grid lines
 scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.3)",
 
 //Number - Width of the grid lines
 scaleGridLineWidth : 1, 
 
 //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
 bezierCurve : true,
 
 //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
 pointDot : true,
 
 //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
 pointDotRadius : 5,
 
 //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
 pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
 
 //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
 datasetStroke : true,
 
 //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
 datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
 
 //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a colour
 datasetFill : true,
 
 //Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
 animation : false,

 //Number - Number of animation steps
 animationSteps : 60,
 
 //String - Animation easing effect
 animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",

 //Function - Fires when the animation is complete
 onAnimationComplete : null
};


//Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");


new Chart(ctx).Line(data,options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

> PHP code :- (above js code)

```
<?php 

$array = array(65,68,75,81,95,105,130,120,105,90,75,70);

$res = json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    array("label"=> row['id'], "y"=> row['value']),
    array("label"=> row['column1'], "y"=> row['value1']),
    array("label"=> row['column2'], "y"=> row['value2']),
        );

?>
```