# Error: You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I create a google chart using MYSQL-PHP-JSON-Javascript the code for the chart is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load = google.load || google.charts.load;
    google.setOnLoadCallback = google.setOnLoadCallback || google.charts.setOnLoadCallback;
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

      var options = {
            title: 'Req',
          is3D: 'true',          
          width: 750,
          height: 450,
          slices: [{'color':'#581845'},{'color': '#900C3F'},{'color': '#C70039'},{'color': '#FF5733'},{'color': '#FFC300'},{'color': '#DAF7A6'},{'color': '#3498DB'}]
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

When I load the page it shows me an error:

> You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView.

A refresh on the page removes this error and displays my pie chart perfectly.

I have read the posts on google forum/stackoverflow and added the extra code

```
google.load = google.load || google.charts.load;
google.setOnLoadCallback = google.setOnLoadCallback || google.charts.setOnLoadCallback;
```

and also added the loader.js script. Nothing seems to fix this problem.
Is there something else that can be done to fix this problem?

I used this to create the json table: [PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994282/php-mysql-google-chart-json-complete-example)

My Json table is like:

```
({"cols":[{"label":"Components","type":"string"}, 
{"label":"Count","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"SWa"},{"v":600}]}, 
{"c":[{"v":"Sris"},{"v":142}]},{"c":[{"v":"Sgri"},{"v":86}]},{"c": 
[{"v":"Shw"},{"v":36}]},{"c":[{"v":"Syus"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Other"}, 
{"v":21}]},{"c":[{"v":"yutf"},{"v":45}]},{"c":[{"v":"yutr"},{"v":11}]},{"c": 
[{"v":"duh"},{"v":4}]},{"c":[{"v":"Fgth"},{"v":5}]},{"c":[{"v":"Sys"}, 
{"v":34}]},{"c":[{"v":"Opyu"},{"v":6}]},{"c":[{"v":"jth"},{"v":78}]},{"c": 
[{"v":"Unspecified"},{"v":1}]}]});
```

So this is what goes into google.visualization.DataTable and the dataTable is passed to the variable data:
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

Comment: how is this php related?

Comment: I use mysql with php to create the json table i use for the data of the google chart. Referring this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994282/php-mysql-google-chart-json-complete-example

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner How is this unclear? what more information would you require?

Comment: Because; people such as I / others, expect to see related code which is misleading. That's what makes it unclear.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I have added the link to the code in php-mysql i followed here.

Comment: The first time the page loads are you calling `draw()` with any data at all? I don't see that method in your code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I call draw at the end with the data: "chart.draw(data, options);"

Comment: Is it expecting any data when you load the page?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes the data is in the jsonTable i create following:: PHP MySQL Google Chart JSON - Complete Example

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have added the link that shows its relationship to php as i mentioned before.

Comment: I work mostly with PHP/MySQL. I am not your guy for JS, sorry Aastha.

Comment: @WhiteHat Ive edited the question to provide more information. When the page first loads I get the google visualization error but after a refresh of the page, the charts load perfectly.

Comment: @WhiteHat This fixed the problem! thanks!

Comment: The visualization package was also changed from 1 to 1.0, 1.1 acc to google forum discussions and nothing worked except this.

Comment: For ref Google forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/viiQ4x70soc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `jsapi` and just use `loader.js`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

when using `loader.js`, the `load` statement should be...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

and the callback...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```