# generating graph with static data using Google Charts

Tags: php, graph, google-visualization

I want to generate graph for my static data. I am using [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) for doing this. Here is the google chart code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But i want to put my code in this. I am not getting how to do it. Here is my code

```
<?php
echo '<div align="center" style="width:100%; padding-top:20px;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td class=tddash>10 latest purchase orders</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>';
        $SQL = 'SELECT purchorders.orderno,
                        suppliers.suppname,
                        purchorders.orddate,
                        purchorders.deliverydate,
                        purchorders.initiator,
                        purchorders.requisitionno,
                        purchorders.allowprint,
                        purchorders.status,
                        suppliers.currcode,
                        currencies.decimalplaces AS currdecimalplaces,
                        SUM(purchorderdetails.unitprice*purchorderdetails.quantityord) AS ordervalue
                    FROM purchorders 
                    INNER JOIN purchorderdetails 
                    ON purchorders.orderno = purchorderdetails.orderno
                    INNER JOIN suppliers
                    ON purchorders.supplierno = suppliers.supplierid
                    INNER JOIN currencies 
                    ON suppliers.currcode=currencies.currabrev
                    WHERE purchorders.orderno=purchorderdetails.orderno
                    GROUP BY purchorders.orderno,
                        suppliers.suppname,
                        purchorders.orddate,
                        purchorders.initiator,
                        purchorders.requisitionno,
                        purchorders.allowprint,
                        purchorders.status,
                        suppliers.currcode,
                        currencies.decimalplaces LIMIT 5';
                        $SalesOrdersResult2 = DB_query($SQL,$db);
                        $Total = 0;
                echo '<table width="100%" celpadding="2" class="selection">';
                        echo '<tbody><tr><th> Supplier </th><th>Order Date</th><th>Delivery Date</th><th>Initiator</th><th>Order Total</th><th>Status</th></tr></tbody> ';
                        $k=0;
                while ($row = DB_fetch_array($SalesOrdersResult2))
                    //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($SalesOrdersResult))
                    {
                        if ($k == 1){
            echo '<tr class="EvenTableRows">';
            $k = 0;
        } else {
            echo '<tr class="OddTableRows">';
            $k = 1;
        }
                        $FormatedOrderValue2 = locale_number_format($row['ordervalue'],$row['currdecimalplaces']);
                        $Total += $row['ordervalue'];
                        //$FormatedOrderValue1 = locale_number_format($myrow['ordervalue'],$_SESSION['CompanyRecord']['decimalplaces']);
                        $FormatedOrderDate1 = ConvertSQLDate($row['orddate']);
                        $FormatedDelDate1 = ConvertSQLDate($row['deliverydate']);

                        echo ' <td> ' . $row['suppname'] . ' </td>';
                        echo ' <td>$FormatedOrderDate1</td><td>$FormatedDelDate1</td><td> ' . $row['initiator'] . ' </td><td>$FormatedOrderValue2</td><td> ' . $row['status'] . ' </td> ';

                    }
        echo '<tr><td colspan="3">Total---</td><td colspan="2">$Total</td></tr></tbody>';           
        echo '</table></td>';


     echo' </tr>
    </table>

</div>';
```

Can somebody plz help me in this?

*** EDITED ***

```
echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
   echo ' <script type="text/javascript">


      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "1getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

          alert(jsonData);



       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
         var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
         view.setColumns([0, 3]);
         var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
      chart.draw(view, {width:400, height:240});
      }
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>';
echo '</head>'; 
<div id="chart_div" ></div>
```

1getData.php

```
<?php

$PageSecurity=0;
include('includes/session.inc');
if (!isset($RootPath)){
        $RootPath = dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
        if ($RootPath == '/' or $RootPath == "\\") {
            $RootPath = '';
        }
    }

    $SQL = "SELECT workorders.wo, woitems.stockid, stockmaster.description, stockmaster.decimalplaces, woitems.qtyreqd, woitems.qtyrecd, workorders.requiredby, workorders.startdate
FROM workorders
INNER JOIN woitems ON workorders.wo = woitems.wo
INNER JOIN stockmaster ON woitems.stockid = stockmaster.stockid
ORDER BY workorders.wo";
                    $searchresult = DB_query($SQL, $db);
                    $table=array();

                    $table['cols']=array(
                    array('label'=>'ITEM', type=>'string'),
                    array('label'=>'Description', type=>'string'),
        array('label'=> 'QTY Required', type=>'number'),
        array('label'=>'QTY Outstanding', type=>'number')

);
$rows=array();


                    while ($row = DB_fetch_array($searchresult))
                    {

            $qreq = locale_number_format($row['qtyreqd'],$row['decimalplaces']);
            $qout = locale_number_format($row['qtyreqd']-$row['qtyrecd'],$row['decimalplaces']);


                        $temp=array();

        $temp[]=array('v' => $row['stockid']);
        $temp[]=array('v' => $row['description']);
        $temp[]=array('v' => $row['qtyreqd']);

        $temp[]=array('v' => ($row['qtyreqd']-$row['qtyrecd']));

        $rows[]=array('c' => $temp);


                    }
                    $table['rows']=$rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
print $jsonTable;




?>
```

but it displays only two columns, where as i want to display 3

---

JAVA SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">


      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "1getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

          alert(jsonData);



       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
         var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
         view.setColumns([0,3]);

         var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
      chart.draw(view, {width:400, height:240});

      }
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any errors? Wrong graph? No graph?

Comment: Yeah, i have edited my code above, i am not getting any result for that :(, if i put `<?php echo $mbflag; ?>`, it gives blank screen again

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685745/google-chart-tools-with-php-mysql

Comment: i have tried it. Its really helpful. I am able to display my graph but only two columns am able to display. Not getting why the 3rd column is not getting displayed.

Comment: i have edited my code , request you to have a look

Comment: Try to copy the working columns to see if that's working. I think it would work, so check your input variables to the chart then (of the third column).

Comment: i checked by displaying the data, and its proper. but second bar is not getting displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `view.setColumns([0, 3])` tells Google charts to only display the first and fourth column in your data. Add the columns you want to display to the array.

Comment: If i use `view.setColumns([0, 4])`, it doesn't display the chart only :(

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding you. From what I can see in your code, you probably want, `view.setColumns([0,3,4])`. Try that.

Comment: nothing actually, the is getting displayed properly, don't know why this is happening :(

Comment: Can you post the JS that's generated by your PHP. It's almost impossible to debug PHP to some random internet user's database. Additionally, what browser are you using.

Comment: I have pasted my java script above, and am using Chrome

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with the data returned from you AJAX call. I'm not an expert there, but I know DataTable cannot take JSON as an input to the constructor. It has to be a JSObject. If you convert the JSON to a JS Array, does it work?

Comment: I dont know how to convert JSON to a JS Array, i will search and will try